# How to convert the OBJMTL models into export types in assimp?

Tags: c++, json, assimp

How can we convert the OBJMTL models into json, any command available to do it?? because the models should be here in object.obj and object.mtl files, how can we combine them and convert it into json??

here is the command to convert the obj model alone, it is working well

```
assimp export female02.obj female02.stl
```

how can do it with the .mtl files for the same model?? and texture material also not applying to models if we use alone .obj files only

Answer (score 0):

A Python converter is availabe which converts OBJ format into Three.js JSON format

```
python convert_obj_three.py -i file.obj -o file.js
```

Link: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/converters/obj/convert_obj_three.py